# How can I receive Bluetooth audio signal and forward it to a Bluetooth speaker?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, microcontroller, esp32, bluetooth-5

I need some help because I don´t know how to approach this challenge.

I want to build a device, that's receiving a Bluetooth audio signal and is forwarding it to a Bluetooth speaker. It´s also running some algorithms with the audio data and also simultaneously sending results via UDP to a different device.

I already thought about using two or three ESP32s, using one with an extra Bluetooth module, or searching for a whole different MCU with Bluetooth 5.0 or higher and Wifi 5GHz. But I don´t know approach the best is, or maybe a completely different one.

Some context, why we want to do it:
We want to create a real-time light show, based on the current playing song. It is already working for PC, but also want to make it accessible for phone users. Sadly there is no way to capture the internal audio on iPhone or Android phones. Our Idea to make the music sync with the phone possible is that you are connected with the phone via Bluetooth to our "sync box" which is then connected to the speaker via Bluetooth or AUX. The "sync box" is running our algorithms for creating the light shows and then sending the data to the microcontrollers from the light strips.

So maybe you have an idea how we can sync the lights to the music completely differently or how I can approach the challenge with Bluetooth.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks a lot.